# concatenate column when another column duplicates

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

[image]

How can I make the table looks like below turn into concatenated form

```
1844|a 
1847|a,b
1848|34,qaz
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day,

This question was asked with the tag "sql-server-2012", but I can't feel good to give the answer without first show how simple it is to solve these type of questions with [new function STRING_AGG that was added to SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql).

Therefore, **First I will add the code for the sample DDL+DML** (create the relevant table and insert sample data), which is something that the person who ask the question must ad to the question, but was not added here

**Secondly I will show the solution in SQL Server 2017 and above**

And **finally I will give the solution for older versions** like SQL Server 2012

Have fun, and I recommend to read all

### DDL + DML

> NOTE! **Instead of posting images and stories on your table, it is always better to present us a simple way to reproduce the issue!** This means that when you have question related to queries, then you should provide us with queries to create a sample table (including the indexes) and to insert sample data. In addition you should add the requested result, which was provided here.

```
/*************************** DDL+DML */

drop table if exists T; -- this work only from SQL Server 2016
create table T(id int, txt nvarchar(10))
GO

INSERT T(id,txt) 
values (1844,'a'),(1847,'a'),(1847,'b'),(1848,'34'),(1848,'q')
GO

Select * from T
GO
```

### Solution for SQL Server 2017 and above

```
/*************************** Solution */
-- New from 2016: STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator )  
-- New from 2017: STRING_AGG ( expression, separator ) [ <order_clause> ]
SELECT id,STRING_AGG(ISNULL(txt,''), ',') WITHIN GROUP (order by id)
from T
group by id
GO
```

#### Solution for old versions of SQL Server

> This solution was taken from this blog:
>   http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/152/Unsplit-Using-For-XML-with-group-by-columns.aspx

```
SELECT
    id,
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ',' + t_in.txt
            FROM T t_in
            WHERE (t_in.id  = t_out.id)
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ),1,1,''
    ) AS NameValues
FROM T t_out
GROUP BY id
GO
```

I hope that this solve the question ;-)

Comment: I was going to mark this question as a duplicate, however your answer is better than the answer given for the question I had in mind, so... +1.

Comment: Thanks. Great to see you here Zohar, As you can noticed I just came to visit stackoverflow a bit :-)